Using webassembly with web workers and CDN
I'd like to use a webassembly module in a web worker. There are three files in the game: library.wasm, library.js and library-worker.js. Everything works fine if all of these are hosted on the same server with a worker code like this:
importScripts ('library.js');

onmessage = async function (ev)
{
    let lib = await library ();
    // do some cool stuff
};

My problem happens when I try to use a version of the library that is hosted in another server, something like this:
importScripts ('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/library@0.0.1/dist/library.js');

onmessage = async function (ev)
{
    let lib = await library ();
    // do some cool stuff
};

The main js file is loaded successfully, but it still looks for the library.wasm file locally. Is there any way to make it load the wasm file from the same cdn as the js file?

The request to create the WASM context is made from the file in the CDN? Are you the author of that lib? Does it absolutely need to be classic JS (i.e. would switching to ESM be an option?)

Yes, the wasm request is made from the js file. I’m the author of the library (https://github.com/kovacsv/occt-import-js) so its possible to modify that as well. I prefer keeping it as js so its not bundled with the main application.

ESM is js. It's just that your to start your Worker you'd need to define it with { type: "module" }, but IIUC your lib does create the Worker, so that shouldn't be an issue. If it is, it's also possible to load the scripts through dynamic import(script) calls.

Meanwhile I've found the solution. It's possible to overwrite wasm search path like this:
importScripts ('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/library@0.0.1/dist/library.js');

onmessage = async function (ev)
{
    let modulOverrides = {
        locateFile: function (path) {
            return 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/library@0.0.1/dist/library.wasm';
        }
    };
    let lib = await library (modulOverrides );
    // do some cool stuff
};

